# Клиент для записи данных в memcached.sock по ключу в C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, memcached

Есть сервер memcached работающий на unix сокетах (/var/run/memcached.sock).
Как в C# записать данные в memcached по ключу?

Comment: .NET Core / .NET 5?

Comment: Копать куда-то сюда `Socket socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP); socket.Connect(new UnixDomainSocketEndPoint("/var/run/memcached.sock"));`

Comment: .NET Core : 2.2

Comment: Socket socket = new Socket() ... не дает записывать по ключу, а только Send() на сокет и все, а нужен полноценный memcached

Comment: Значит вы не в курсе, что такое сокет. Изучайте матчасть. Сокет - это поток, поток работает по протоколу. Вы можете отправить команду приложению в поток, по  ключу или нет, это уже вам решать. Сокет - это всего-лишь транспорт, который умеет передавать байты и принимать. Какие именно байты вам надо передавать и принимать - смотрите наверное в документации memcached. Вы спросили как подключиться к UNIX сокету - я подсказал, если для вас это не то, значит вы не то спросили.

Comment: Быть вы [это](https://github.com/enyim/Memcached2) искали? Только вам потребуется минимум .NET Core 3.0 (netstandard2.1), рекомендую сразу ставить 3.1 последний.

Comment: aepot, спс за разъяснения. Насколько я понимаю, есть 2 вида применения сокетов. 1-й для отправки потоковых данных в некий стек, применяется , например, в играх, в мессенджерах, здесь ключей нет, просто поток данных пишется в сокет. 2-й способ - для временного хранения данных и быстрого доступа к ним, это применяется например в memcached, здесь данные пишутся в виде пары значений "ключ=значение". Так вот мне нужен 2-й способ - классический memcached. И, поправлю чуток, вопрос был не как подключиться а как записать данные по ключу, то биш записать пару значений "ключ=значение".

Comment: Вышеуказанный способ Socket socket = new Socket() пробовал, но не нашел в нем метода для записи пары "ключ=значение", есть Send(), но нет ключей.

Comment: Я вам выше дал ссылку на библиотеку, которая реализует протокол общения с memcached, ее можно установить из NuGet, но нужен .NET Core версии 3.0 и выше. Но вы так и не поняли, что такое сокет, и для чего он нужен.